# how is better deploy (install) this application?

Tags: c#, architecture

I have an application that has two main parts. First, the client, basicly is the user iterface, second, a repository that is a library, that connects with the database and has all the logic to insert, update, delete... and ensures the coherence of the data.

The application is not deplyed yet, and by the moment the client uses directly the repository to access to the database. But when I will have to deploy the application to be used for many users, inside the LAN, I think that this is not the best solution.

First solution

Install the client and the repository in all the computer of the users that need the application.

This have the disadvantage that when I update the application, I have to update many applications, and perhaps not all the applications are updated because of any reason. So if the update is of the repository that fix some problem, if the client that has not updated the application will introduce incoherence data in the database, if the fix is to correct this type of problem.

Second solution

The client use direcly the repository, but the application is installed in a network drive. I have only one installation, so if I need to update the application, I have to do it once.

The application is not so big, about 12MB, but it could be a bit slow because has to go through the net from the server to user computer. So perhaps some user could copy the application to the local computer, so I can't ensure that happens the problem with the first solution.

Third solution

The client application does not use the repository directly, the repository is in the server and the client use WCF to communicate with the server, and the server uses the repository to access to the database.

The disadvantage is that the server has to run the repository, so if there are many clients connected, it needs a lot of RAM, instead that if the computers of the users have the application in local, the memory is needed in the local computer.

In sumary, when I have to deply this kind of application, which is the best solution, or which is the solution that would you use in your projects?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your deployment method, are you using a ClickOnce to deploy it?  If so you could keep the data local to each PC, avoid those RAM issue, and if you send out a new update change the required version number and set it to check prior to running, that way they will be unable to run the program without updating it.  The problem is they must have network access, but this would also be an issue with remote data.  In this situation you would only need network access during the update, not sure if this would be an issue or not.

Comment: Really I didn't know the option of ClickOnce to deploy the application. I will see. Thanks for the suggestion.